# Grid system in xs only not in md

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have 14 buttons, in phone (xs), I would put them in a row, and use `class="col-xs-6"` so they end up in a tidy 2 x 7 formation. For desktop (md), I am certain they will fit so they can just stay on one line.

However when viewing on desktop, I don't need the grid system at all. I can just display as inline. There are two reasons to this:

- 14 buttons can't fit into 12 cols. Even with nested rows, you will be fitting 7 buttons into 12 cols, still nasty.
- Using grid and row means each button has to be equal width. If I have a tiny button that says "Go" and another one that says "Internationalization" their width must be multiplication of the width of one column, if not equal.

I found a way by putting 14 buttons in a row in a `<div class="visible-xs-block">`. For desktop I just put 14 buttons directly (without row) into a `<div class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block">`

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I am much against the idea of having duplicated code and having to maintain both of them every time something gets updated. Thanks!

Comment: You can override the bootstrap to use 14 cols instead of 12 : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Comment: This does not solve the second reason I don't want the elements to use grid system.

Comment: Yes it's just a way to have 14 cols, a comment, not an answer... I'll post an answer. Please wait a minut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be with media queries.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">1</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">2</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">3</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">4</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">5</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">6</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">7</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">8</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">9</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">10</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">11</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">12</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">13</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 inline_from_sm"><button class="btn btn-info">14</button></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .inline_from_sm{
    display: inline-block;
    width: initial;
    float: initial;
    padding: initial;
    }
}
```

[**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/H5QMXp6tdA](http://www.bootply.com/H5QMXp6tdA)

**Post Scriptum:**
*In this code it's for "sm" 768px

For "md" you should use 992px

For "lg" 1200px*

Comment: Is the exclusion of a `<div class="row">` intentional (so it works in sm and upwards)?

Comment: It was for fiddle it's was not clear when full width so I changed for container..., you can change to 'row' there is no problem